# How to insure there is no pagebreak between detail sections of a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

In my Crystal Report I have four detail sections. I want this section stay on one page together. For example if there is not enough space for all SECTIONS on one page, then all four sections should go to the next page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need at least one level of grouping on your data for this to work, but begin in the design tab of your report and right click on the group name and select "Change Group" from the menu.  Then go to the Options tab and check the check box for Keep Group Together.

This will keep all sections of the group and the details sections within together on a page.  If they don't fit, the whole group will begin on a new page and will only push data into a second page if the entire group and all of its contained sections do not fit on one page together.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate this functionality in the `Section Expert` you select on the left the Menu `Details` and then you have to check the option on the right `keep together`.